# Unfold/expand tree when undoing

Tags: org-mode, code-folding

When I hit the wrong key in a folded org-mode buffer and I hit undo, the cursor normally jumps to some folded location and it's pretty hard to understand what is going on.

Expanding the parents of the current location after hitting undo does not seem to expand the right branch (it just positions me somewhere else?).

Would it be possible to make it so that, when undoing, the parts of the tree that are being touched are fully shown?